# operator<< cannot use an IT member of its friend, array

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, typename

i suppose that, if i make operator<< a friend of 
a data struct (array by name);

```
//Forward Declarations
template<typename S, typename T> 
struct array;

template<typename U, typename V>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& ous, const array<U, V>& t);
```

then, i will be able to do something like this; inside the implementation of operator <<

```
//operator<< is a friend of struct array{} already
template<typename T, typename U>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const array<T, U>& var){

    if(var){
        /*Error: 'IT' was not declared in this scope*/

        for(IT it = var.data.begin(); it != var.data.end(); it++){
            /*and i thought i need not redeclare IT before using it
             since operator<< is a friend of array already*/
        }
    }
    else{cout << "empty";}

    return os;
}
```

Now, here is array's implementation:

```
/*explicit (full) specialization of array for <type, char>*/
template<>
template<typename Key>
struct array<Key, char>{ 

     //data members
     map<const Key, string> data; 
     typedef map<const Key, string>::iterator IT;

     //member function
     friend ostream& operator<< <>(ostream& ous, const array& t);

     //other stuff/functions
};
```

lastly, the compiler is angry when i test-drove it like this;

```
void Test(){
     array<int, char> out;
     out[1] = "one";            //Never mind. this has been taken care of
     out[2] = "two";            
     cout << out;               //Error: 'IT' was not declared in this scope
}
```

Question:
what exactly am i doing wrong, or, why can't i dirrectly access and use 
IT (a typedef within array), even after i had declared operator << (that requests IT)
as a friend of the array struct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write

```
for( typename array<T, U>::IT it = var.data.begin(); it != var.data.end(); it++){
```

And change

```
typedef map<const Key, string>::iterator IT;
```

to

```
typedef typename std::map<const Key, string>::const_iterator IT;
```

Here is a demonstrative program where instead of the `std::map` I used `std::array` for simplicity. I think it can help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct A
{
    std::array<T, N> a;

    typedef typename std::array<T, N>::const_iterator IT;
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const A<T, N> &a )
{
    for ( typename A<T, N>::IT it = a.a.begin(); it != a.a.end(); ++it ) os << *it << ' ';

    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    A<int, 10> a  = { { { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } } };

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: thanks ! but i needed to understand what's going on. i have also edited: ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const _Tarray<T, U>& var) to: ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const array<T, U>& var) above.

Comment: @OsagieOdigie By default without typename the compiler considers the name as not a type name.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `IT` inside your template the compiler looks in the current scope (the operator template) for a declaration of a type named `IT`.

This fails because you defined the type as part of your array struct.

So in order to use the `IT` type you need to fully qualify it by using `array<T,U>::IT`.
Or you could try `auto` instead if you're using C++11.